# How to specify only the path when exporting a file in scrapy?

Tags: json, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, export

I'm using scrapy and I'm trying to export files, I have some spider and I was wondering if it is possible to specify only the path, using FEED_URI worked, but only with the name of the file together.

```
FEED_URI = 'file:///C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/data.json'
```

If I leave it at that, the file will overwrite the previous one.

I wanted something like this,

```
FEED_URI ='file:///C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/'
```

but that I could specify when crawling, like this

```
scrapy crawl name -o filename.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [parameterize the feed URI](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#storage-uri-parameters).